# Quit Mathematica kernel if no license available

Tags: command-line

I'm running the Mathematica kernel `math` from inside a makefile to generate C++ code, like so:

```
a.out:
        g++ -o a.out main.cpp

main.cpp:
        math -run "<< \"generate_main.m\"" # generates main.cpp
```

However, sometimes there is no Mathematica license available on the machine where `make` is called (license has expired, connection to license server has been lost, ...).  In such a case, the Mathematica kernel does not quit, but instead waits for the user to input a license password.  So, `make` will never finish.  In such a case, I'd like `math` to quit with a non-zero exit code.  How can this be achieved?

Most convenient would be a command line option for the Mathematica kernel, like `-quit-if-no-license`.  `math -quit-if-no-license` could then for example also be used in a `configure` script to check if the Mathematica kernel can be run.

Comment: Why just not simply call math with simple test calculation like:  echo "2+2" | math -run | grep "4" ?

Comment: Your can always give it some limited time to complete. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23145/run-a-command-for-a-specified-time-and-then-abort-if-time-exceeds         I think you cannot test if license is valid unless you run math (or of course unless you know how to check if generated license file is valid, which is equivalent to know how to crack math :-))

Comment: what happens when you start math with the -script option and there is no license? (I seem to recall that in my experience it simply quits) You can then reset `$BatchInput` to move out of batch mode.

Comment: Sorry, I have to correct myself: The proposal of @user18792 works very well, because `stdin` is closed after `echo "2+2"` has finished. If `stdin` is closed and the correct license password has not been entered, Mathematica returns with the exit code `1`. This non-zero exit code can be checked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no option -quit-if-no-valid-license-found, though probably one should exist. However, the Python module Pexcpect seems to just work (after a bit of tweaking delaybeforesend ). So install it by `sudo yum install pexpect.noarch` or 'sudo yum install pexpect.noarch' and then e.g. copy this to 
m.py  :

```
import pexpect
child=pexpect.spawn('math')
child.delaybeforesend = .2
child.sendline('<<"myCode.m";')
child.sendline('')
child.sendline('')
child.sendline('')
child.sendline('')
child.sendline('')
```

and, for testing myCode.m :

```
Export["date.txt", DateString[] <> "\n", "Text"];
```

and running 
    python m.py
will not hang, even if you have no Mathematica license.
Instead of newlines you could probably also use id.send(chr(3)).